# Need a SQL Query to fill out values so that every missing option is present in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has just raw data: A contact in one column, and an option they chose in another, like so:

```
Contact Option
A        1
A        3
B        1
C        2
D        3
E        2
E        3

TableOfOptions
1
2
3
4
```

And what I want is to return a result set that has a contact for each option, regardless of whether it was chosen. Basically, I want to "fill out" the result set, with NULLs for options not chosen. So there are two tables, one with the Contact to Option Choice mapping, and one with a list o fall the options. The desired result set looks like this.

```
Contact Option Chosen
A       1       1
A       2       NULL
A       3       3
A       4       NULL
B       1       1
B       2       NULL
B       3       NULL
B       4       NULL
C       1       NULL
C       2       2
C       3       NULL
C       4       NULL
```

Etc, etc, I'm sure you get the point. I'm can't figure out how to project out every row in the 'options' table for each contact in the "ContactOptions" table, filling out the missing rows with NULLs for the OptionChosen. Every "contact" will have at least one choice of option, some may have several, some may have all. So I need to "add" between 0 and "n-1" options to each Contact row, with all the "added" rows being NULL.

My first though was a CROSS JOIN and have a CASE WHEN x.Option = y.Option then x.Option else NULL END for the third column... but I'm finding that in some cases I'm getting duplicate rows, and I can't figure out why.

Note my real world example is slightly more complicated in that I want to carry many more properties than just one (i.e Contact A has four other properties I want repeated with each option, but I figured that didn't have much to do with the solution). But the combination of "Contact + Option" should be unique in the result set.

My end goal is to be able to query for a given option, but always get ALL contacts. For example, if I want to see "How did people choose option 2", I want A through E to each have ONE row in the result set, with either a value or a NULL based on whether they chose the option or not.

**EDIT**: Here's sample code that I've tried, but which results in lots of duplicate rows I don't want:

```
CREATE TABLE ContactOption ([Contact] CHAR(1), [Option] int);
INSERT INTO ContactOption ([Contact], [Option])
VALUES
('A', 1),
('A', 3),
('B', 1),
('C', 2),
('D', 3),
('E', 2),
('E', 3);

CREATE TABLE TableOfOptions ([Option] int);
INSERT INTO TableOfOptions ([Option])
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

SELECT co.[Contact],
       t.[Option],
       CASE WHEN co.[Option] = t.[Option] THEN co.[Option] ELSE NULL END AS [Choice]
FROM ContactOption co
     CROSS JOIN TableOfOptions t
ORDER BY co.[Contact], t.[Option]
```

Comment: Showing us what you tried makes it a lot easier for us to tell you why it osm't working. Please do put your attempts in the question.

Comment: @forpas I don't see how LEFT JOIN is going to get me what I want. I need all options for all contacts.

Comment: @Larnu updated with my attempt. I don't want to just throw a DISTINCT in there, as I need this to be really performant (imagine millions of rows) and I want to be able to add WHERE clauses to be able to focus on a single choice (show me all contacts and whether they chose option 2 or not), or being able to left joint to the full universe of contacts (from a contact table that has A-Z for example).

Comment: If you don't have a table with all the values for `Contact` you're going to need a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: usually this is an OUTER join.

Comment: @Larnu, I just want this table's contents, only fleshed out. So if there are two Es in the table, I want four in the results. If there is one A in the table, I want four in the results. I always want 4... I just want the "options" table to FILL IN the missing options for a given contact. And the part I'm missing is how to have something FILL IN THE GAPS, rather than duplicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a table with the distinct values for `Contact` you will need at least 1 `DISTINCT` here, to get those `DISTINCT` values:

```
WITH Contacts AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT CO.Contact
    FROM dbo.ContactOption CO)
SELECT C.Contact,
       TOO.[Option],
       CO.[Option]
FROM Contacts C
     CROSS JOIN dbo.TableOfOptions TOO
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ContactOption CO ON C.Contact = CO.Contact
                                   AND TOO.[Option] = CO.[Option];
```

Comment: This works. I hope it scales well. Thanks!  (I was hoping for some SQL magic to "fill in gaps" but this works, so it's what I'll use.

Comment: *"I hope it scales well."* it *probably* won't, @pmbAustin . If that's important, you should have a table for the unique values of `contact`, then you can drop the CTE with the `DISTINCT` and reference the (new) table instead.

Comment: @pmbAustin . . . It should be fine if you have an index on `(contact)`.